# Is L={0^n 1^n ∣n≥0} context free language?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free, pumping-lemma

I looked through many sources which give this as an example for cfl. It also makes sense according to this:
[image: Properties of CFL]

But it fails the pumping lemma test.
Let's take n=5.
According to the Pumping Lemma, we can decompose
s into uvxyz like:
u=0, v=0, x=0,y=01, z=111

If we pump it, it clearly fails.
So, is 0^n1^n context free or not?

Comment: You don't get to choose the pumping length and you don't get to choose the decomposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have just shown that the given language does not meet the condition of the pumping lemma for $n=5$ and **one particular decomposition**.

To conclude that $L$ is not context free you need to show that the language does not meet the condition of the pumping lemma for some word of **sufficiently large length $n$** and **all** decompositions of such word (within the constraints of the pumping lemma).

It turns out that the words of $L = \{0^n 1^n \mid n \ge 0\}$ admit a valid decomposition as soon as $n \ge 1$.
Here is a decomposition of $0^5 1^5$ into $uvxyz$ that can be pumped: $u=0^4$, $v=0$, $x=\varepsilon$, $y=1$, $z=1^4$.

This is not surprising, since $L$ is indeed context-free as the argument in your question shows.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was unaware of the fact that the language had to be proven against every decomposition for a length n. I was taught something different. Your answer has really cleared up things for me.